# NodeJS - Express - console to navigate in database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've created a simple nodeJS Express API, and it's working.

`I've created my API with a MongoDB (mongoose) database`

But after many search, I didn't find how to navigate (see, update, delete etc) in my database from the local.
(as if I do `rails console` for Ruby on Rails.)

Any Idea to do something equivalent ?
(or not, just need to see and modify my DB)

thanks !

Comment: Is the [Mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/access-mongo-shell-help/) what you're looking for? Are you trying to access a MongoDB instance on your local machine or on a server?

Comment: Actually Both, 
Thanks for the mongo shell, it's usefull ! What about when it's on a server

Comment: That depends on the server you're using, and what access you have in to it. If you can ssh in, then you could use the mongo shell from there the same way you use it locally.

Comment: in the mongo shell, do `mongodb://<username>:<password>@<databaseURL>:<port>/<dbName>` . If you have rights like mentioned above, you will be able to connect